# My device is grayed out on Google Play website

Tags: google-play-store

Recently I had some trouble with google play app - first, I was getting "connection error" when using wifi. I cleared the app chache, uninstalled updates and after I played with it a bit more, it completely stopped woking giving me the "connection error" also on 3G.

I erased my device and installed CyanogenMod 10.1.

Now the Google Play app woks great but when I go to Google Play website, my device seems to be out of sync - it is grayed out and the list of apps installed is out of date.

How to fix this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) and use its "Manage Android ID" function to update your device ID and "Market Doctor" to relink apps to the market

Comment: Very cool. Would the OP need their previous device ID or does TB take care of that? If so, how could you find the device ID that the Play store is looking for?